# Catch a SQLAlchemy Warning

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When using SQLAlchemy's built-in `get_columns` method, I sometimes receive the following warning:

`SAWarning: Did not recognize type 'geography' of column 'column_name'`

How would I go about catching and handling that warning? This doesn't seem to work:

```
try:
    inspector = inspect(engine)
    columns = inspector.get_columns(table_name)

    return columns

except exc.SAWarning as sawex:
    logger.error(sawex)
    <do something here>
```

Comment: could you add `create table` sql?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a warning and not an exception, thus, your except clause is never executed.

Since 'geography' is a type that is specific to the [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geography.html) PostgreSQL extension (which isn't enabled by default), it isn't really surprising that sqlalchemy doesn't know that type.

So, to eliminate the warning you have to make the 'geography' PostGIS type known to AQLAlchemy. Either by importing the [GeoAlchemy](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package or by adding the type otherwise.

---

From the [GeoAlchemy documentation](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_tutorial.html#reflecting-tables):

```
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry  # <= not used but must be imported
```

i.e. for our example:

```
from geoalchemy2 import Geography
```

---

Alternatively, to just make the type known without having to install another Python package:

```
import sqlalchemy
import sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes
import sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base

class GEOGRAPHY(sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.TypeEngine):
    __visit_name__ = "geography"

    def __init__(self, point_type, srid):
        # e.g. 'PointZ'
        self.point_type = point_type
        # e.g. '4326'
        self.srid = srid

sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.base.ischema_names['geography'] = GEOGRAPHY
```

So this eliminates the warning, but when - say - inserting a geometry value, you can't directly supply a tuple, but have to prepare some appropriate string, e.g.:

```
location = f'POINT({longitude} {latitude})'
```

Similarly, when selecting you have to extract the coordinates inside via select expressions.